# limit number of rows returned after executing a query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, zend-framework

I am using ZEND MVC framework and after executing a query in my modal part (table section) the query returns 12 rows. I am passing the returned rows in the service section and further on passing the result to controller which would give me the final view for front end.

I want to limit the number of rows to be 3 in my view section. I cant use LIMIT 3 in my query since I am further interactiing with other queries and comparing the result so I need to have all 12 rows. Would it be possible to somehow put the limit in the service section?

Here is my code. Although I don't need to put every bit of my code but this would give an clear idea.

Modal (table part)

```
 public function getJobTopStatements( UserJobEntity $activeJob, $intervalInMonths = NULL ){

        if($intervalInMonths){
            $interval = ' AND ss.datetime < ADDDATE( NOW(), INTERVAL -'.$intervalInMonths.' MONTH) ';
        }

        $testQuestionTable = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('testQuestionTable');
        $questionAnswerTable = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('questionAnswerTable');
        $testAnswerTable = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('testAnswerTable');

        $query = 'SELECT
                t.id,  
                t.text,
                t.key,
                s.answer
        FROM '. $testQuestionTable->getTable() .' AS t
        LEFT JOIN '. $questionAnswerTable->getTable() .' as s ON (s.testQuestionId = t.id)
        LEFT JOIN '. $testAnswerTable->getTable() .' as m ON (m.id = s.testAnswerId AND
              m.id = (SELECT MAX(ss.id)
                    FROM ' . $testAnswerTable->getTable() . ' as ss
                    WHERE ss.userJobId = '. $activeJob->getId() .'
                    '.$interval.'
                )
        )
        WHERE m.userJobId = '. $activeJob->getId() .'
        GROUP BY t.id
        ORDER BY m.id DESC, s.answer DESC';

        return $this->adapter->query($query, 'execute')->toArray();
    }
```

This query returns 12 rows and I am passing the result into service section as follows

```
public function getActiveJobTopStatements(){

        $activeJob = $this->userService->getUserActiveJob();

        if(!$activeJob){
            return array();
        }

        $result = $this->testAnswerTable->getJobTopStatements( $activeJob );
        return $result;
    }
```

and finally the controller part return this view

```
$view->jobTopStatements = $testAnswerService->getActiveJobTopStatements();
```

Is there any way I can put limit in the service section so that it will only pass 3 rows instead of 12?

Comment: Possibly add an argument to `getActiveJobTopStatements` that specifies the max number of results, defaulted to `0` for all?

Comment: Do you mean limiting MYSQL using the [LIMIT](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm) function?

Comment: @Mr Jack thats right. If I put LIMIT function in MYSQL it would only give me 3 rows, but I need all 12 rows for further calculation with other queries.

Comment: Calling it only once, you seem to store it in an array, which you could then [slice](http://ca2.php.net/array_slice) -- Calling it twice you could just give different limits for each call.

Comment: Alright I can modify my result like this
$result = $this->testAnswerTable->getJobTopStatements( $activeJob );
  $result = array_slice($result, 0, 3);
        return $result;
I would give me 3 rows for sure,  but I am concerned is there any side effect?

Comment: @Nish Doing that makes result only 3 rows. You need to slice after you returned it, only for the function you use it in.  What bit of code calls getActiveJobTopStatements()? 

$view->jobTopStatements = $testAnswerService->getActiveJobTopStatements();

Then add another variable $topthreeJobStatements = array_slice($view->jobTopStatements, 0 , 3 );

Comment: I'm agree with Mr Jack. You can have a second array like `$result2 = array_slice($result, 0, 3);`. With this, you can display $result2 and continue to work with $result.

Comment: @Mr Jack getActiveJobTopStatements() functions uses the result from getJobTopStatements() which returns 12 rows and the result from getActiveJobTopStatements() further going down to the controller part. Well, slicing the result in getActiveJobTopStatements() does the job and return only 3 rows in the view part. I need to check the calculation if it is correct or not. Otherwise view part looks fine to me. Thanks for reminding me about array_slice. You can put that as an answer - I will accept that :-)

Comment: Yeah, I will try returning the result into another array instead of slicing the original array. Thanks guys